# Computation of inverse of a matrix having dimensions 25000 by 25000 In R

Tags: r

I want to compute the inverse of a 25000 by 250000 matrix. I tried to compute the inverse by using the `solve()` function but I got the following error:

```
Can not allocate the memory of size 3.9GB
```

Please let me know how to solve this problem in `R`.

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to even hold both a 25000x25000 matrix and its inverse in memory at the same time? Each matrix has 625,000,000 entries, each of which will take 8 bytes. If the original matrix is sparse, you could look into using a sparse matrix library.

Comment: Also -- do you really need to invert that matrix? See ["Don't invert that matrix" - why and how](https://www.r-bloggers.com/dont-invert-that-matrix-why-and-how/) from the R-bloggers site (if nothing else, that post should make you aware of the [matrixcalc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixcalc/index.html) package). Even for smaller matrices, inversion is often not necessary. Round-off error is often an issue, and with a matrix of that size it could be substantial (even if you could hold the result in memory).

Comment: I have 4GB RAM. Also, I have tried to compute the same using sparse library but unfortunately I got the same error.

Comment: With 4GB, you can't possibly hold such a large matrix in memory (especially since e.g. the R process itself, etc. needs to use RAM). If you can fit the original matrix, there are algorithms which can compute an inverse in-place. I don't know if there are R implementations of them.

Comment: 25000*25000*8/1024/1024/1024 = 4.65GB.  If you have 4GB of physical RAM you won't have enough.  Your OS and R itself have memory requirements.  How much of your RAM is allocated to R?

Comment: I have increased the memory limit by using memory.limit() function. I also have the 8 GB RAM PC. I have tried the same in 8GB RAM. But again I am facing the same problem.